# Physics textbook for mathematicians

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations

Before this post gets marked as duplicate, I've checked book [book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) among other posts but I don't think they really answer this fairly niche question.

I am looking to compile a list of books, online courses, or other resources, that **assume an advanced level of mathematical comprehension** (graduate level at least), and yet no more than a **junior-senior highschool level physics understanding**.

I've been working as a mathematician for several years, specifically in the information security industry, and I am interested in steering my career in the direction of computational physics, purely due to curiosity.

More specifically, I'm after something that is,

1. More fast paced than a first year - university text book,
2. Takes the student from topics of, for eg. the 17th century to the present,
3. Assumes very little physics understanding,
4. When presenting physics problems or exercies, emphasizes deriving computational models rather than analytic solutions to trivial questions,
5. At the very least, presents a roadmap of what to learn (excluding mathematical prerequisites) above teaching it

Note 1: Apologies again if this can be marked as duplicate. However I can't find a suitable resource for a mathematician who is a beginner in physics. I've always found books progress either too slowly that I need to skim faster than I can comfortably skim a book without missing out on the good parts, or assume too much physics knowledge without redirecting to background reading.

Note 2: If this is indeed not a duplicate, I will be sure to add it in to the book recommendations thread.

If you can spare a moment or two to point me in the right direction, I hope I will be able to repay this forum with more constructive questions and answers in the future if I can reach the same level as you.